# Determining execution time of queries in SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am creating a program for analyzing and generating queries.  I was curious if there currently exists a method within SQLite such that I could query the time taken for a query to process?  I am unable to modify my install in any way, so this method needs to work out of the box.  I am writing my tool in python, and although I guess I could use the timer class to time execution -this method will not work when I am connecting to remote machines (and return a consistent timing.)

Comment: Hmmm... Even though you are connecting to remote machines, shouldn't you still worry about the time it takes to execute/process the whole thing? after all, that's pretty much all end users care about

Comment: And also, why would you want to time the execution time only? Comparisons made between ex. times across different machines aren't very useful.

Comment: Only connecting to remote machines (release) to profile how long queries are taking on their machines.  Normally the profiling is done on the local (development) machine.  The round trip time is not wanted for analyzing the time whcih queries take to execute on each machine.

Comment: Can't you have the script execute on the remote machine?

Comment: Nope :( Need to telnet in and call sqlite3 directly and parse the results.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From within the sqlite3 command-line program you can do:

```
.timer ON
select * from my_table;
```

This will print the CPU time taken for the query.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Tim, thats pretty much exactly what I needed.

Comment: Tim, is there a way to invoke these special commands from python using the sqlite3 library?  I need an operational error when I try to execute .timer ON... It does however appear to work when I am using the CLI tool.

Comment: You can use the "-cmd" command line argument.  So you would do something like 'sqlite3 -cmd ".timer ON" [SQLQUERY]'

Comment: @sampwing: All the commands starting with `.` are specific to the command line tool (SQLite itself is oblivious to them).