# how to find out the execution time of Sqlite query in android

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite

I'm trying to optimize the performance of my Sqlite queries.

I wanted to know if there is any way to find the execution time of each Sqlite statement, or if there is any tool that allows to view the statement execution time in Android SDK?

Although I'm familiar with `.timer On` and `.timer show` commands for Query timer.

**Example:**

[image: Query Exceution time]

Any answer is truly appreciated!

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948270/determining-execution-time-of-queries-in-sqlite I think it answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this in Java:

```
int startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

... // Execute the query here

int executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; // This variable now contains the time taken by the query, in milliseconds
```

Comment: @Nemmondommegav This is What i was looking for...thks

Answer (score 7):

Instead of calculating the execution time by yourself, let sqlite do that for you.
From [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDebug.java#L56):

```
/**
 * Controls the printing of wall-clock time taken to execute SQL statements
 * as they are executed.
 *
 * Enable using "adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteTime VERBOSE".
 */
public static final boolean DEBUG_SQL_TIME =
        Log.isLoggable("SQLiteTime", Log.VERBOSE);
```

Therefore, to enable execution time tracing run:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteTime VERBOSE
```

You will have to restart your application for reloading new settings**. Right afterwards you will start to see these log records in logcat:

> 02-14 12:27:00.457 11936-12137/osom.info.dbtest I/Database:
> elapsedTime4Sql|/data/data/osom.info.dbtest/databases/test.db|1.000
> ms|UPDATE TestTable SET key=? WHERE _id=1

** Sometimes this won't be enough, so run `adb shell stop` and `adb shell start`.

To stop printing these logs either restart the device (this property is not persisted between reboots) or set the property to a higher log level, i.e.:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteTime ERROR
```

---

Note for those that are using [Jetpack's Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room): this solution will work with Room as well (since Room uses Sqlite as underlying DB).

Comment: @Napolean It will work as long as Room uses Sqlite as underlying DB.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, it works with Room as well. You should update this answer and add note for Room's usage, it will be useful for people.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

in your code to know the time took in running the query...

```
   t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
   //Execute query
   t2=System.currentTimeMillis();
```

then (t1-t2) will give you the time difference.
   Once i made android benchmarking app used this method to calculate how different smartphones perform  based on sql query execution.
   Hope it Helps.